# Extra Collection View Cell is Created with Attributes in CoreData

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I am trying to display collection view cells that contain text, this text is retrieved from CoreData and is set up like this:

```
var tasks : [Task] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myCollView.delegate = self
    self.myCollView.dataSource = self

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext // This one causes blank cell
    let tasker = Task(context:context) // Causes blank cell

    tasker.pid = idVar // Causes blank cell

    var hello = tasker.pid

    print("In next view")
    print(hello!)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tasks.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "connectCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]

    cell.labelTe?.text = task.name

    self.myCollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 25

    cell.tag = indexPath.row

}

func getData() {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
    tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
    }

    catch {
     print("Get Data failed")
    }

    // Fetches data.

}
```

This is how the collection view is created, however in the previous view controller I have a prepareForSegue function that sends a string to a variable in the current view controller and that variable gets saved into another attribute under the same CoreData entity like this:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let tasker = Task(context:context)
    tasker.pid = idVar // idVar is the variable that stores the string

    print(tasker.pid!)
```

The problem happens when I run the app, I click on a collection view cell from the previous view controller and segue to the current view controller but than it shows a blank collection view cell with no text, when I go back and click on the previous view controller cell and segue to the current view controller, then the there is another blank collection view cell.

I found out that the error is coming fro the lines in viewDid load that I added the comment after. When I removed those 3 lines then problem was gone although I need to assign idVar's value to tasker.pid. I am not sure how to do this without the error. I feel like the error is coming from the numberOfItemsInSection as it refers to Task the entity and not the name attribute. However I cannot specify the attribute. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: did you check `tasks` value available ?

Comment: @NazmulHasan I cannot use tasks because it is an array used to store the string values that relate to the text inside the collection view cells. I also cannot access tasks.pid as it gives an error. I think the problem is that with numberOfSection I wrote tasks.count which I think might be counting the new attribute and adding it to the total number of cells. If I could specify 'var tasks : [Task.name] = [] I think the problem would be solved but I can't do that as it also gives an error. I still have no solution, thanks for the input.

Comment: Best practices my be doing like this way. var tasks : [Task]?

Comment: @NazmulHasan It doesn't work when using 'var tasks : [Task]?' instead of 'var tasks : [Task] = []'. I tried it but got an error asking me to force unwrap many values. I also attempted creating another variable assigned to Task and attempted using that in place of [Task] however that did not work. Thanks! :D